# Reducing size of pytorch library

Tags: github, pytorch, python-telegram-bot

I've made a conversation telegram bot with pytorch and I'm trying to host it onto Github. The large pytorch file prevents me from doing so as its too large and I get this error:

**remote: error: File env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_cpu.dylib is 233.61 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB**

Is there anyway to reduce the size of the torch file? Or is it possible to find and delete unused dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

Do not host that file on github.
Make a requirements.txt file and add required versions there, you can even fix version required to run your code.

Whoever downloads it can create a virtual environment (venv) or a docker image and install it as

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

For example:

**requirements.txt**

```
https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-1.5.1%2Bcpu-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl
transformers==3.5
```